# Opencart Issue document.cookie Alert on Page Load

Tags: cookies, opencart, reload

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juIPA.png)One of my client's Opencart website have issues when open the website, a prompt alert shows following code:

```
Conflict

<script>document.cookie = "humans_21909=1"; document.location.reload(true)</script>
```

How to get this resolve. Also help me to find the files where they are located to fix it.

Comment: This is not relevant to default opencart. Please mentioned your opencart version and snapshot here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have 'VERSION', '2.3.0.2'. and here is the screenshot. http://i66.tinypic.com/mhnqf.png

Comment: Here is [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54549132/1140335) of this issue.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue, it only happened to me when the request was something to do with "register", in my case it was "register.php", I only changed the documents name and problem was solved

Comment: Seems a behavior that not only affects to Opencart. In my case I was using laravel.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the filename of register.php and its occurrences on all places in the files.

Comment: Do you mean register.php in catalog/controller/account/register.php  right? Where are other register files? I still have the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In register_modal.tpl find this part (for me 582 line):

```
error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
}
```

Comment this alert.

Enjoy!

Comment: I can't see register_modal.tpl file. I can only see the register.tpl file inside views. Please remember I have 'VERSION', '2.3.0.2'. And I've commented the above error part inside register.tpl. Error still not going. Should I clear any cache?

Comment: How this post will answer the question?  You have to find the solution for the problem, not to hide it.

Answer (score 0):

It might be happening because of your function name is 'register' so you need to change the function name to some other name and check it.