# humans_21909=1 error in codeigniter project

Tags: php, codeigniter, localhost

Some controller functions in codeigniter is setting up **humans_21909** cookie. And the page source appears to be as follows

```
<script>document.cookie = "humans_21909=1"; document.location.reload(true)</script>
```

The same project worls perfectly on local server. but on live server it shows this stuff.

Comment: Search `humans_21909` and you'll see a lot of topics.

Comment: This does most likely not come from codeigniter or have anything to do with PHP. There are a lot of posts about this where people are running different frameworks/applications.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55915264/scriptdocument-cookie-humans-21909-1-document-location-reloadtrue-scri/59068984#59068984

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a network related issue. I just switched my internet connection to different wifi and it works fine. Don't know more about this error but it solved by this way.

Comment: Did you find any workaround for this? What was the original issue?

Comment: I'm an iOS dev and was facing this issue when calling the web service. PHP guy was saying that web service is working fine at his end. So I just switched my internet to another connection then it started working.

Comment: but that is not the solution right? I am also facing the same issue but want to figure out the right solution

Comment: This is the solution because this is the problem with your network not with the code or at back end.

Answer (score 2):

Just change the name of the function which returns that error. eg from register() to account_register().

Comment: it worked for me, in my routes I changed 'register-user' to 'user-registration' and it worked like charm..Thanks buddy

Answer (score 1):

Once I degraded the PHP version, the error has gone. 
May be because codeigniter deperciated syntax or some other features in the new version. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have found that issue is coming from cookie.
Please set a cookie in header.php file with project path
in this after set of cookies page will reload without changing web URL

e.g

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getCookie(name) {
  var value = "; " + document.cookie;
  var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
  if (parts.length == 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
}
var accept = getCookie("humans_21909"); 
if (accept !="1") {
document.cookie = "humans_21909=1; path=/insert here project root path/"; 
    console.log("ok"); 
    (function()
    {
      if( window.localStorage )
      {
        if( !localStorage.getItem('firstLoad') )
        {
            console.log("refresh");
            localStorage['firstLoad'] = true;
            window.location.reload();
        }  
        else
          localStorage.removeItem('firstLoad');
      }
    })();
}
```

I think your issue with resolve with this

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error as shown in the image below :

[image]

you can see I am getting error code **409 conflicts**
and error message :

```
<script> document.cookie = "humans_21909=1"; document.location.reload(true) </script>
```

So in my case issue was because my API name which is **register.php**
and it was giving an error on mac os, not on windows.
So I renamed the API **regsiter.php** to **registerApi.php** and it solved the issue.

If you are also using any **reserved** name for your API name or any method try changing it. Hope it will help.