# Post request return script from live server but works on local server

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Post request to add a user from vue.js to laravel api gives response as document.cookie = "humans_21909=1"; document.location.reload(true) with a 409 conflict. I am not uploading any file just simple form data which works fine locally but when on live server, does not work and give this script in response. Kindly help me. 
[image: error]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [humans\_21909=1 error in codeigniter project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54303995/humans-21909-1-error-in-codeigniter-project)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Can you please provide more information about your steup, the code you are using to fulfill the request. The code in the backend and what you've already tried to inspect the issue?

Comment: Try to delete your cookies

Comment: The change of the internet works but not permanently and the downgrading from 7.2.1 to 7.1.1 does not change anything. Kindly help. @jerodev

Comment: I have deleted the cookies and nothing changes. @dparoli

Comment: @frank I have uploaded the image of postman hitting the api url : https://i.stack.imgur.com/29Rf2.png  Any kind of assistance will be much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the screenshot. Your first step should be to validate that the request is actually reaching your backend. You should test this for both, get & post requests. Just try to `dd('test')` for some of your endpoints and check if you receive results. If you want us / me to help more you should provide at least your routes definition, your controller method definition and information about your backend setup (windows, ubuntu  apacache, nginx)

Comment: Thanks to everyone. But it is working now, I changed my route url from register to reg and function name from register to reg1 and it started working. I don't know how but may be the  issue of unique keywords like register in laravel was causing the problem (still don't know).

Comment: Also had the same issue and changing route and its name solved the issu

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem with the fact that the route is /register. Laravel seem to have a problem with that, although I do not have the technical details as to why.

Renaming the route (path and name) actually solves the problem e.g changing the route to `/signup` or any other thing apart from `/register`

Comment: this was the issue in my case while dealing with a php api. Renamed to signup.php & got my sleep back :)

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this error two times and fixed it in different ways just change in route.

like

```
  Instead of this 

  {{base_url}}api/admin/get-contact-insurer/109
```

Into

```
{{base_url}}api/admin/getContactInsurer/109
```

if your route is like the above without dash then use a reverse of this method.
hope this is help full for you.