# IP API in php smarty template engine

Tags: php, ajax, smarty, ip-address, form-submit

I used the php smarty template for development, and when i use ip location finder API of user submitting a form on my website, the form could not be submitted, instead, in view source, it shows

```
<script>document.cookie = "humans_21909=1"; document.location.reload(true)</script>
```

i used this url for collecting user ipo address on form submit:

```
function getfromipdata_lon(){
    $query=@unserialize(file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/php/'.$ipdataloc));
    return $query['lon'];
}


function getfromipdata_lat(){
    $query=@unserialize(file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/php/'.$ipdataloc));
    return $query['lat'];
}
```

Can I know whether the smarty templating engine conflicts with this ip API ? or is there any other conflict?

Comment: You've got a couple of problems, neither of which are Smarty related. Search humans_21909=1 and you will see that some hosting providers do this is you have a URL that conflicts with some built-in functionality https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54997928/post-request-return-script-from-live-server-but-works-on-local-server#comment96800393_54997928

Comment: The other probmem is that you seem to be calling the ip-api service twice - once for lat and once for lng - just call it once and get both attributes from the reponse.

Comment: @RobRuchte i think, after reading the link you mentioned in your comment, that there is any conflict in either reserved keyword or so.. should I rename my variables in the form? Please answer

Comment: From what I understand, it’s the URL that you form submits to. Nothing to do with Smarty.

Comment: @RobRuchte by the way, the url is my domain name followed by /contact slug, and it is there for all the pages of the website, that components(php files) are  named and then the templates file is named same as the php file. e.g. abc.php in the components folder and abc.tpl in the templates folder ... and i have applied the ajax in my contact form, i can show you the code.. of .tpl file and of .php file

Comment: @RobRuchte [Please check my code here and please let me solve my issue asap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67446083/php-smarty-contact-form-not-submitting-on-some-isp-networks)

Comment: The code isn’t the problem, you can’t use the contact slug. Just search google for humans_21909=1 for details, that’s all I did to spot the problem. You’re over thinking this.