# Contact form works in safari (desktop) but nothing else

Tags: php, google-chrome, mobile-safari, contact-form

I have a basic contact form that sends to my gmail account. This form works in Safari on my Mac but its does not work in Chrome or Opera, nor does it work on my iPhone.

The website is whataprettyface.ca/whataprettyface_new/index.html

I can get the form working in all browsers and devices when the success message is a link to a separate thank-you.html page. But I am looking for it to work the way it does currently in safari with the overlay success message.

HTML:

```
 <form method="POST" class="ajax-form" data-message-class="colors-d background-95 heading border" action="contact.php">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 control-group">
            <div class="alt-placeholder">Name</div>
            <input type="text" name="name" value="" size="40" placeholder="Name" data-validation-required-message="Please fill the required field." required>
            <div class="help-block"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 control-group">
            <div class="alt-placeholder">Email</div>
            <input type="email" name="email" value="" size="40" placeholder="Email" data-validation-required-message="Please fill the required field." required>
            <div class="help-block"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 control-group">
        <div class="alt-placeholder">Message</div>
            <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message" data-validation-required-message="Please fill the required field." required></textarea>
            <div class="help-block"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 form-actions">
            <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </div>
    </div>
 </form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
$errors = '';
$myemail = 'my.email@gmail.com';//
if(empty($_POST['name'])  || 
   empty($_POST['email']) || 
   empty($_POST['message']))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
}

$name = $_POST['name']; 
$email_address = $_POST['email']; 
$message = $_POST['message']; 

$successMessage = 'Message sent successfully!';

if (!preg_match(
"/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", 
$email_address))
{
    $errors .= "\n Error: Invalid email address";
}

if( empty($errors))
{
    $to = $myemail; 
    $email_subject = "CONTACT VIA WHATAPRETTYFACE $name";
    $email_body = "\n Name: $name \n Email: $email_address \n Message \n $message"; 

    $headers = "From: $myemail\n"; 
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";

    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

    echo($successMessage);
}
```

I also have gen_validatorv31.js as a linked script.

Comment: Does it have any error info when the App doesn't work? Can you see any logs via Chrome Dev tools?

Comment: any error that you were facing?

Comment: You need to do more debugging in the future. Issue is that you are getting a 409 status code on the form submission to the PHP processing.

Comment: Have a look at the [Qustion to document.cookie = humans_21909](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56035540/5841606) You get back the following in a Response with the HTTP Status Code 409 `<script>
document.cookie = "humans_21909=1";
document.location.reload(true)
</script>`

That is the same issue another user was facing in the linked question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [<script>document.cookie = "humans\_21909=1"; document.location.reload(true)</script>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55915264/scriptdocument-cookie-humans-21909-1-document-location-reloadtrue-scri)

Answer (score -1):

So thanks to some the comments to the original post I was able to correct the issue by by removing the word 'contact' from my html. It now says 'kontact.php' and that spelling was reflected in the name of the php file itself.