# Flutter + Laravel : can't register new user on server

Tags: laravel, flutter, request

I have flutter app with this register request :

```
var url = 'xxxxxxx/api/v1/';
  // register-----------------
  registerToApp(password, username, email, context) async {
    var newurl = Uri.parse(url + 'register');
    var data = {
      'password': password,
      'username': username,
      'email': email,
    };
    if (username == '' || password == '' || email == '') {
      showSnackBar(context, 'Username and Password and Email must be fill');
    } else {
      try {
        var response = await http.post(newurl, body: data);
        var result = jsonDecode(response.body);

        Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;
        prefs.setString('username', result['username']);
        prefs.setString('token', result['token']);
        showSnackBar(context, result['status']);
        return result;
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
    }
  }
```

when I tested it on local server it success but after I upload the same api to server I get this error on VsCode :
`<script>document.cookie = "humans_21909=1"; document.location.reload(true)`

I tested the api on postman on localhost it is succes too on server I get error 409 conflict.
the api created by Lumen :

```
public function register(Request $request)
   {
       $id=CreateRandomId::get_id('users');

       $password = password_hash($request->password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
       $users_count= User::where('username',$request->username)->get();
       $email_count= User::where('email',$request->email)->get();

       $credentials = request(['username', 'password']);
       
       if(count($users_count)>0){
           $data = [
               'status' => 'username found',
           ];
       }
       else {
           if (count($email_count)>0){
               $data = [
                   'status' => 'email is found',
               ];
           }
           else {
               
               $user = User::create(
                   [
                       'id'=>$id,
                       'username'=>$request->username,
                       'password'=>$password,
                       'email'=>$request->email,
                       'role'=>'user'
                   ]);

               if($user){
                   $credentials = request(['username', 'password']);

                   if (! $token = auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
                       return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
                   }
                   else{
                   $data = [
                       'username'=>$request->username,
                       'password'=>$password,
                       'email'=>$request->email,
                       'status' => 'success',
                       'token' => $token
                   ];}
               }
               else{
                   $data = [
                       'status' => 'failed',
                   ];
               } 
           }
       }
       return $data;  
   }
```

I copied same controller and router to server ,but don't work, what can I do ?

the route is :

```
$router->group(['prefix'=>'/api/v1'],function () use ($router) {
    $router->get('/',function (){
        return "welcome";
    });
    $router->group(['prefix'=>'/'],function () use ($router) {
        $router->post('/register','AuthController@register');
        $router->post('/login','AuthController@login');
```

Comment: please paste your routes and middleware for the route group too.

Comment: @GopalKohli the register route don't have middleware it is simple route : `$router->post('/register','AuthController@register'); `, but I will put them on question

Comment: I found solution here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54303995/humans-21909-1-error-in-codeigniter-project#:~:text=Just%20change%20the%20name%20of%20the%20function%20which%20returns%20that%20error.%20eg%20from%20register()%20to%20account_register().
I just renamed register route