# When a page or ajax request is made to the app then it returns a script cookie response. Need guidance

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5

When a page or ajax request is made to the laravel app then it returns a script cookie response. Need help!
I dont know what is creating this.
This is not annoying on page load but creates a problem in get ajax requests.

```
<script>document.cookie = "humans_21909=1"; document.location.reload(true)</script>
```

People facing this issues in other frameworks as well|
No Solution anywhere.

[Opencart Issue document.cookie Alert on Page Load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53629218/opencart-issue-document-cookie-alert-on-page-load)

[humans_21909=1 error in codeigniter project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54303995/humans-21909-1-error-in-codeigniter-project)

Comment: Why have you tagged this question with two different version of laravel?